# Loop isn't looping from generate_series

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm creating a plpgsql function to populate a lookup table for date information. My loop statement is only doing the first date, it isn't looping through the additional days.

```
  DECLARE
startDate ALIAS FOR $1;
endDate ALIAS FOR $2;
currentDate date;
dateDate integer;
yearDate integer;
monthDate integer;
dayDate integer;
weekDate integer;
dayofWeekDate integer;
weekofYearDate integer;
quarterDate integer;

BEGIN
DELETE FROM date_data;

FOR currentDate IN (SELECT * FROM generate_series(startDate::date,endDate::date,'1 day') s(currentDate)) LOOP
    yearDate := (SELECT date_part('year', currentDate));
    monthDate := (SELECT date_part('month', currentDate));
    dayDate := (SELECT date_part('day', currentDate));
    weekDate := (SELECT date_part('week', currentDate));
    dayofWeekDate := (SELECT date_part('dow', currentDate));
    quarterDate := (SELECT date_part('quarter', currentDate));
    weekofYearDate := (SELECT date_part('week', currentDate));
    dateDate := to_char(currentDate,'YYYYMMDD');

    INSERT INTO date_data VALUES ( dateDate, yearDate, monthDate, dayDate, FALSE, dayofWeekDate, FALSE, NULL, FALSE, NULL, weekofYearDate, quarterDate);

    RETURN dateDate;
END LOOP;
END;
```

I'm expecting it to loop through the time series inserting the expected values, however it is only inserting the first date and not continuing on.

I'm calling the function with SELECT add_date_data2('2018-01-01','2019-01-01');

Thanks.

Comment: Because you return in the loop's body.

Comment: @stickybit Thank you. Moving the Return did resolve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you code uses lot of anti-patterns that significantly decrease a performance

1. cycle over query instead int cycle

   ```
   FOR IN SELECT * FROM generate_series ..
   ```
2. useless queries in assignment

   ```
   var := (SELECT expr)
   ```

So your code can be rewritten to one SQL `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO date_data
   SELECT to_char(d::date,'YYYYMMDD'),
          date_part('year', d::date),
          ...
     FROM generate_series(startdate::date, enddate::date, '1day') g(d);
```

or very classical:

```
WHILE d < enddate
LOOP
  yearDate := date_part('year', currentDate);
  monthDate := date_part('month', currentDate);
  dayDate := date_part('day', currentDate);

  INSERT INTO date_data VALUES ( dateDate, yearDate, monthDate, dayDate, FALSE ...
  d := d + interval '1day';
END LOOP;
```

Expressions are evaluated 10x faster than functional same queries - so use queries only when it is necessary - more, your code will be much more readable and cleaner.